# how to get rid of exception while generating PDF using iText

Tags: java, spring-mvc, pdf-generation, itext

I wast trying to render pdf using itext in java spring framework mvc. 
Here's my filter class.

```
 public class PdfFilter implements Filter, ApplicationContextAware {

@SuppressWarnings({ "UnusedDeclaration" })
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PdfFilter.class);
protected ApplicationContext applicationContext;

public void init(FilterConfig config) {
    /* do nothing */
}

public void destroy() {
    /* do nothing */
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
        FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

    // Check to see if this filter should apply.
    if (!"pdf".equals(request.getParameter("reportViewType"))) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }

    // Capture the content for this request
    ContentCaptureServletResponse capContent = new ContentCaptureServletResponse(
            response);
    filterChain.doFilter(request, capContent);

    response.setContentType("application/pdf; charset=UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition",
            "attachment; filename=\"report.pdf\"");
    response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "-1");

    try {
        // Get the html content
        String htmlContent = capContent.getHtlmContent();

        PdfGenerator pdfGenerator = new PdfGenerator(
                response.getOutputStream());

        pdfGenerator.renderPdf(htmlContent, request, response);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }
}

public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}
}
```

and here's my pdfGenerator class 
    public class PdfGenerator {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PdfGenerator.class);
    private OutputStream outputStream;

```
public PdfGenerator(OutputStream os) {
    this.outputStream = os;
}

public void renderPdf(String htmlContent, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    log.debug("renderPdf");

    htmlContent = cleanUpHtml(htmlContent);
    htmlContent = addHeadBodyTag(htmlContent);

    htmlContent = addCss(htmlContent);

    log.debug("convertToXhtml-e:");
    OutputStream xhtmlOs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
    tidy.setXHTML(true);
    tidy.setCharEncoding(Configuration.UTF8);
    tidy.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlContent.getBytes()), xhtmlOs);

    xhtmlOs.flush();
    xhtmlOs.close();
    log.debug(xhtmlOs.toString());
    StringReader contentReader = new StringReader(xhtmlOs.toString());

    InputSource source = new InputSource(contentReader);

    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
            .newDocumentBuilder();
    // documentBuilder.setEntityResolver(new MyResolver(request));
    documentBuilder.setEntityResolver(new NoOpEntityResolver());

    Document xhtmlContent = documentBuilder.parse(source);

    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocument(xhtmlContent, null);
    renderer.layout();

    renderer.createPDF(outputStream);

    outputStream.close();

}

private String cleanUpHtml(String data) {
    log.debug("cleanUpHtml-e:");

    data = HtmlUtils.removeAllTags(data, "<script", "</script>", null);
    data = HtmlUtils.replaceAll(data, "<a .*?>|</a>", "");
    // data = HtmlUtils.replaceAll(data, "<img .*?>|</img>", "");
    data = HtmlUtils.replaceAll(data, "<link .*?>", "");
    // remove hidden field
    data = HtmlUtils.replaceAll(data, "<input.*?type=['\"]hidden['\"].*?>",
            "");
    // remove pagination from lister
    data = HtmlUtils
            .replaceAll(
                    data,
                    "(<div style=\"top: .*?px; position: absolute;\" id=\"pager\" class=\"pager\".*?</div>)",
                    "");

    return data;
}

private String addHeadBodyTag(String data) {
    // data = "<html><head></head><body>" + data + "</body></html>";
    return data;
}

private String addCss(String data) {
    log.debug("addCss-e:");

    return data;
}

private String addHead(String data, HttpServletRequest request) {
    log.debug("addHeader-e:");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(500);
    String header = sb.toString();
    data = HtmlUtils.replaceAll(data, "(<body.*?>)", "$1" + header);

    return data;

}

private String addFooter(String data) {
    log.debug("addFooter-e:");

    String footer = "iit lone gunmen 2.0";

    data = HtmlUtils.replaceAll(data, "(<body.*?>)", "$1" + footer);
    return data;
}
```

}

but somehow Im getting some exception:

```
 Jan 26, 2012 5:43:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/govForms]       threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.Rectangle.getHeight()F
at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.writePDF(ITextRenderer.java:339)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.createPDF(ITextRenderer.java:315)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.createPDF(ITextRenderer.java:246)
at bd.gov.forms.web.pdf.PdfGenerator.renderPdf(PdfGenerator.java:64)
at bd.gov.forms.web.pdf.PdfFilter.doFilter(PdfFilter.java:54)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.parsePage(PageFilter.java:119)
at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:55)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any kind of help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

NoSuchMethod error suggest that you have a mismatch of versions of the libraries that you are using. I would start with checking my library dependencies and find if some libraries are not expecting different versions of iText. If so, I would try to exclude one dependency or choose libraries version which support proper versions of iText.

If you are using Maven, try: mvn dependency:tree and check for multiple iText occurence

Comment: Im not using maven:(. added itext-paulo-155.jar and Tidy.jar.

Comment: Are you sure you are using proper version of iText? I can see that the most recent version is 5.1.3 - http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/iText/iText5.1.3/.

I am almost sure that you are using old API. If you were following some tutorial, try to see if it is up-to-date. Maybe iText has been extended and grew over time? I think that even packages has changed (based on contents of the 5.1.3 lib). You will have to upgrade to the most recent version.

Comment: Ok, let me know if it helped. Also checkout those:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/index.html
http://www.dzone.com/links/r/pdf_with_java_and_itext_tutorial.html

Answer (score -1):

The process of PDF generation can fail for a wide variety of reasons. 
You must surround the pdf generation in a try/catch block and, in the catch block, make some sort of error handling. I see 2 basic way to handle the problem:

1. Deploy your app with a default pdf document: in the catched generation exception serve the content of the default pdf, which would contain a generic warning phrase of failed generation
2. The pdf generator return the result in a stream of bytes (and not directly in the response  output stream) and only if return correctly, you set up the response headers to serve the generated pdf and copy the byte returned in the response output stream; in the catched generation exception you set up the response to serve a html page describing the error or you can redirect to a standard error page.